# Un printf junto con un While y un Modulo en C me esta enviando una salida errada

Tags: c, while, printf

Estoy aprendiendo C con el libro "Como programar en C/C++ y Java" de Deitel y Deitel en su 4ta edición y estoy haciendo cada una de las figuras de ejemplos y los ejercicios al final de cada capitulo. Tengo un problema de lógica con el ejercicio 3.40 de la pagina 86 debido a que me exige la siguiente salida con unos asteriscos (*):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo con las siguientes instrucciones de salida

printf("* "), printf(" ") y printf("\n")

El detalle es la salida que obtengo que es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que hice:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* inicio del programa con la funcion main */
int main(void)
{
    system("clear");

    int numero = 1,
        modulo;

    while(numero <= 64)
    {
        modulo = numero % 8;

        printf("* ");

        if(modulo == 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
            printf(" ");
        } /* fin de else */

        numero += 1;

    } /* fin de while */

    return 0; /* finalizacion del programa con exito */

}   /* fin de la funcion main */
```

Comment: en esa logica, el espacio en blanco se va a dar cuando el modulo de numero entre 16 sea 0, y el salto de linea cuando el modulo entre 8 sea 0. Creo que con quitarlo del if, y otro if en el que el numero % 2 sea 0 para el salto de linea puedes solucionarlo

Comment: Yo no coloque ninguna condición con el modulo de numero entre 16 aunque si fue buena idea crear  una condición para cada printf, no lo había pensado de esa forma.  Si agrego el salto de linea cada vez que la división entre 2 de resto 0 me va generar  un salto con cada numero par.

Sigo teniendo error pero puedo ver mejor las cosas. Gracias.

Comment: perdon, fallo mio. Te dije el salto de linea con %2 y no es asi. mil perdones

Answer (score 1):

> > Un printf junto con un While y un Modulo en C me esta enviando una salida errada

El problema radica que cada vez que el módulo es `0`, imprimes el espacio. Entonces, deberías verificar que el espacio solo se imprima cuando sea necesario.

Una posible solución es usar una variable booleana. Por defecto le asignamos un `true`, entonces la primera vez que imprimimos la línea de asteriscos, si incluimos el espacio, después en la próxima línea no y así sucesivamente.

En código quedaría así:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h> /* bool, true, false */

int main(void)
{

    int numero = 1,
        modulo;
    bool espacio = true;
    while(numero <= 64)
    {
        modulo = numero % 8;

        printf("* ");

        if(modulo == 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
            //E incluimos el espacio solo si vale TRUE
            if(espacio)
                printf(" ");
            espacio = !espacio;
        } 
        numero += 1;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Otra posible solución para no tener que usar la variable booleana sería esta:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i != 8; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j != 8; ++j)
            printf("* ");
        printf("\n");
        //Si "i" es par, imprimimos el espacio.
        if(i % 2 == 0)
            printf(" ");
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Ya resolví el problema, de todas formas voy a ver el código que me mandaste ya que tu lograste hacerlo de una manera distinta y mas corta que yo,viendo apenas por encima. Voy a copiar copiar y pegar el código para verlo mañana. Muchas gracias.